# Redrawing content of UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a bunch of webviews with static html content that I'm putting in a scroll view as pages.  That works fine, but having 20 something full screen subviews of the scroll view is causing some lag.  I solved that by only placing 5 at a time in there.  The current view, and the two next and two previous.

The problem now is that any web view that is not a subview of the scroll view is not drawing correctly based on the device orientation.  The frame of the webview is printing out correct, but the actual content is drawing in portrait mode.  So there is essentially a strip of blank space to the right of the content.

How do I go about re rendering the content without reloading the page?

Here's the relevant code:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) fromInterfaceOrientation{
    [self resizeSubViews];
}


- (void) setupWebViews{

    if(_webViews == nil)
        _webViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // This is where the navigation would come into play as far as loading up available web views
    [_webViews removeAllObjects];

    // for loop here to create web views
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

        //CDCWebViewController *webView = [[[MyInternalWebView alloc] initWithFrame:_webViewWrapper.frame] retain];

        MyInternalWebView *page = [[[MyInternalWebView alloc] init] retain];


        [page loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:_url]];
        [page setCdcIWVdelegate:self];

        [page setTestIndex:i];
        [page setPageIndex:i];

        [_webViews addObject:page];

        [self loadScrollViewWithPage:i];
    }

    [self clearUnusedWebViews:_pageControl.currentPage];
}

- (void) setupWebViewWrapper{

    // a page is the width of the scroll view
    _webViewWrapper.pagingEnabled = YES;

    _pageControl = [[[UIPageControl alloc] init] retain];

    _webViewWrapper.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    _webViewWrapper.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    _webViewWrapper.scrollsToTop = NO;
    _webViewWrapper.delegate = self;

    _pageControl.numberOfPages = [_webViews count];
    _pageControl.currentPage = 0;

}

- (void) resizeSubViews{

    // The frame is set in IB
    _webViewWrapper.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_webViewWrapper.frame.size.width * [_webViews count], _webViewWrapper.frame.size.height);

    // Move the content offset.
    _webViewWrapper.contentOffset = CGPointMake(_webViewWrapper.frame.size.width * _pageControl.currentPage, _webViewWrapper.contentOffset.y);

    for (MyInternalWebView *subview in _webViewWrapper.subviews) {
        // Reset the frame height and width here?
        CGRect frame = _webViewWrapper.frame;
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * subview.pageIndex;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        [subview setFrame:frame];
    }

}



//*****************************************************
//*
//*         ScrollView Functions
//*
//*****************************************************

- (void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page {

    // Make sure we're not out of bounds
    if (page < 0) return;
    if (page >= [_webViews count]) return;

    MyInternalWebView *webView = [_webViews objectAtIndex:page];

    // Add the preloaded webview to the scrollview if it's not there already
    if (nil == [webView superview]) {
        CGRect frame = _webViewWrapper.frame;

        //NSLog(@"width = %f", frame.size.width);

        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
        frame.origin.y = 0;

        //NSLog(@"setting frame for page %d %@", page, NSStringFromCGRect(frame));

        [webView setFrame:frame];
        [_webViewWrapper addSubview:[_webViews objectAtIndex:page]];

        // Now that the new one is loaded, clear what doesn't need to be here
        [self clearUnusedWebViews:page];
    }


}

- (void) clearUnusedWebViews: (NSInteger) page{

    for (int i = 0; i < [_webViews count]; i++) {

        if ((page - i) <= 2 && i - page <= 2) {
            continue;
        }

        [[_webViews objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview];
    }

}



- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {

    // Switch the indicator when more than 50% of the previous/next page is visible
    CGFloat pageWidth = _webViewWrapper.frame.size.width;
    NSInteger page = floor((_webViewWrapper.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    _pageControl.currentPage = page;

    // load the visible page and the page on either side of it (to avoid flashes when the user starts scrolling)
    [self loadScrollViewWithPage:page - 2];
    [self loadScrollViewWithPage:page - 1];
    [self loadScrollViewWithPage:page];
    [self loadScrollViewWithPage:page + 1];
    [self loadScrollViewWithPage:page + 2];

}
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17257650/826820

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In resizeSubViews, change frames of web views from _webViews array, not scroll view subviews.

Addendum:

- Put check in scrollViewDidScroll if page != _pageControl.currentPage and only then load scrollViewsWithPage.
- Orientation change might and probably will trigger scrollViewDidScroll.
- In clearUnusedWebViews use _pageControl.currentPage instead of page variable. When you're at 5th view and you're loading 7th, you're removing 4th and 3rd even I'd say your intention was to have 3,4,5,6,7 in scroll view at this time.

Comment: All of those are good modifications.  But I still have the same issue with the content.  Seems like the content is starting in portrait mode when it's added to the scroll view and it's not repainting.  Not sure how to force the repaint on the webview.  I know that if I change the orientation, all the web views that are actually attached to the scroll view will adjust fine.  I've tried [UIView setNeedsDisplay] but that doesn't seem to do anything because nothing is happening that warrants the repaint.

Comment: Do you use UIWebView subclass so you can add it to UIScrollView?   I'd say UIWebView reflows page on frame change. Have you tried with scalesPageToFit reset? Or even better would be to find out what's going on in UIWebView on frame change.

Comment: I have a subclass.  I've tried the scalesPageToFit reset.  It doesn't do anything.  The UIWebView doesn't seem to do anything on frame change.  I feel like that's odd.

Comment: Well, UIWebView header reveals this class contains one pointer to UIWebViewInternal. Going deeper, UIWebViewInternal is cluster inheriting lots of classes, of which UIWebDocumentView seems to be of interest to you because it implements methods like  -(void)forceLayout :)  Keep in mind using private API is reason for app rejection.

Comment: Ah.  I ended up releasing any web view I wasn't using and recreating when necessary.  It causes a little bit of a load time if the user flips through the pages really quickly, but it saves a lot of memory.

Comment: @btate Can you please tell me which way you're preventing web views in scroll view acting awkward in your implementation? Tnx!

Comment: @TheBlack What do you mean acting awkward?

Comment: @btate UIWebView class reference says: "Important: You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled." What I wanted to ask is if you observed any issues related to this warning and how did you solve them?

Comment: @TheBlack I saw that and I haven't noticed anything weird.  But I'm doing side paging with the scrollview and The webview content width is always the size of the screen.  So it acts pretty similar to using images for paging in a magazine app except that it's html content and can scroll vertically.

Answer (score 0):

> ### reload
>
> Reloads the current page.
>
> ```
> - (void)reload
> ```
>
> ### Availability
>
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
>
> ### See Also
>
> ```
>   @property request
>   @property loading
> – loadRequest:
> – stopLoading
> ```
>
> **Declared In**
>
> UIWebView.h

[UIWebView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: I've tried using reload, but it causes a lag.  I just need the content that's already loaded to adjust to its frame.

Comment: “[…] without reloading the page”