# Force UIWebView to redraw?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Are there any techniques to cause a UIWebView to redraw itself? I've tried `setNeedsDisplay` and `setNeedsLayout` on the UIWebView and its UIScrollView, but neither have worked.

Comment: can reload do the job ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor It can, but it would require the entire page to reload, which would take *so* very long compared to simple redrawing/relayouting what's already there. I found the solution though.

Comment: what about the `javascript` in the `HTML` content? or the `meta` tag in the `HTML` header?

Comment: @holex Clarify? I found a solution to this already...

Comment: @mattcurtis, you could add `javascript` code for the `HTML` code to refresh itself. you will many examples for it even here, on this site.

Comment: @holex True, but most javascript methods to redraw the DOM are flaky, and don't always work. Or, they're slower than my method below to redraw.

Comment: I encountered this problem when changing the background-color style on the body to match user input. Parts of the UIWebView would not redraw. The approved answer did the trick.

Comment: @Dan_Gabicoware Great! Glad to hear it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Literally found the answer right after asking. The key was to tell the subviews of `UIWebView`'s `scrollView` to redraw themselves - particularly the `UIWebBrowserView`.

```
- (void) forceRedrawInWebView:(UIWebView*)webView {
    NSArray *views = webView.scrollView.subviews;

    for(int i = 0; i<views.count; i++){
        UIView *view = views[i];

        //if([NSStringFromClass([view class]) isEqualToString:@"UIWebBrowserView"]){
            [view setNeedsDisplayInRect:webView.bounds]; // Webkit Repaint, usually fast
            [view setNeedsLayout]; // Webkit Relayout (slower than repaint)

            // Causes redraw & relayout of *entire* UIWebView, onscreen and off, usually intensive
            [view setNeedsDisplay]; 
            [view setNeedsLayout];
            // break; // glass in case of if statement (thanks Jake)
        //}
    }
}
```

I've commented out the if statement to be safe and avoid reliance on `UIWebBrowserView`'s class name not changing. Without it, it hits all UIViews that are in the scrollview, which isn't really a problem at this point (no significant overhead incurred) but could always change.

**EDIT:**

In some cases, the following snippet of JavaScript will accomplish the same/similar thing:

```
window.scrollBy(1, 1); window.scrollBy(-1, -1);
```

You'd think `UIScrollView`'s `contentOffset` would do this too, but that's not always the case in my experience - for some reason `window.scrollTo` is special in this regard.

Gist: https://gist.github.com/matt-curtis/5843862

Comment: Hello, your answer helped me. However, please bare in mind that the way you have commented out the if statement, the for loop only refreshes the first view in the Array, since the break statement is still not commented out. I think it still works because the web browser view usually is the first view, but you might want to edit your solution a bit since the for loop does nothing in this case =)

Comment: @jake_hetfield Thanks - I missed that! I added in the thing about not checking classes as an afterthought in scalability/efficacy and missed the `break` being left behind. 'Preciate it! Glad the answer helped you - helped me too when I was struggling with this problem :) Also reminded me to throw in something else I recalled about this issue.

Comment: This save my life: 
self.wkWebView.evaluateJavaScript("window.scrollBy(1, 1);window.scrollBy(-1, -1);", completionHandler: nil)

Answer (score 0):

This save my life:

```
self.wkWebView.evaluateJavaScript("window.scrollBy(1, 1);window.scrollBy(-1, -1);", completionHandler: nil)
```

Add this line on webview did load delegate event or wkwebview did finish navigation

Thanks MAN!!!!